# Ошибка деления

Tags: c#

вроде все просто, но минут 15 не могу понять что не так и где я на портачил, почему 3 а не 3.63... ?

```
double w = owner.ClientSize.Width / prev_width;// 1680 /462 = 3 (3.63)
```

П.с сори за тупой вопрос, но не могу понять..

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: достаточно только одно число скастовать к типу double.
То есть либо:
`(double)owner.ClientSize.Width / prev_width;`
либо
`owner.ClientSize.Width / (double)prev_width;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

должно быть так:

```
double w = (double)1680/462;
```

Объясню почему. В вашем примере сценарий такой

1. При деление целого числа `1680` на целое `462` результат `3,636363`... получается целым (если он не целый то дробная часть отбрасывается), то есть в результате получается 3 (типа `int`)
2. Получившийся результат 3 (типа `int`) неявно преобразуется к типу `double`.
3. На выходе получаем значение переменной w равное 3.

Comment: извините, а в чем ценность вашего ответа, если абсолютно то же самое ранее  было описано в комментариях?

Comment: ну вообще то я написал (точнее начал писать) ответ, когда еще не было комментариев, когда запостил ответ увидел, что появился комментарий. Что в этом такого?

Comment: @DreamChild , возможно потому, что формат сайта подразумевает ответы в "ответах", а не в комментариях? Комментарий нельзя пометить "правильным ответом". Более того, в таком случае страдает reusability ответа, когда заходишь с поисковика на интересующий вопрос, а ответ в комментах, оказывается.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что делите целое на целое. И ответ будет целое. Наиболее простой способ - почитать первые главы книг и сделать что то в таком виде

```
double w = (double)owner.ClientSize.Width / (double)prev_width;
```

или

```
double w = owner.ClientSize.Width * 1.0 / prev_width;
```